# Paypal Payments Pro - Advanced Fraud Protection not working

Tags: paypal

I need some help with a very annoying problem. We have a Paypal Payments Pro account and use the Paypal_Merchant_SDK (.NET) to process direct payments on our site via API calls using the live credentials we got from paypal.com. We have been live for several months, transactions processing successfully.

Now we want a small change to way we accept payments. We want to reject transactions with wrong CV2 code. So after calls with Paypal support we were told we needed Advanced Fraud protection added to our manager account (manager.paypal.com). So we added it and set the "CSC Failure" fraud filter to reject transactions on non-matches and deployed it to live (active mode). All status messages say it was deployed successfully. We waited for several hours and tested, it didn't work - still processes transactions with wrong CV2 code and we get this message "This transaction was approved. However, the Card Security Code provided had too few, too many, or invalid character types but, as per your account option settings, was not required in the approval process."

Can anyone tell me why the CSC failure setting is not working and how to get it working?

**EDIT**: Ok, on the phone with paypal support again and they say that I will have to use the manager.paypal.com login credentials as part of each transaction in the API calls. Does anyone know where I would do that? I only see fields for API credentials.

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @JayBhatt I know this is a late reply. Long story short, Paypal told us we had to use a different API to take advantage of that feature.